# can't access domain on running instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can access my running instance using public IP but when I try to associate my domain with ec2 instances both NS are the same with the one in hosted zones NS I got a message "can't find the server"

[server names[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpVvI.png)

Comment: to confirm what you are doing, the hosted zone will have a NS record. you have to copy that and then goto the dns management and update the Name servers one by one with the values that you copied. if you have done that. then in the hosted zone, created an `A` record with the value as the ip address of the instance. can you confirm this?

Comment: Arun I've already did that still I get error

Comment: when did you make the NS change . if you have just done that, give it some time.

Comment: I been waiting for 30 minutes still the same

Comment: if you have access to the dig command , try `dig example.com`, it should return an Authority record with reference to amazon

Comment: recently I have done a name server change, i received an email from amazon that the changes are completed. have you received any email.

Comment: this is the email i received, `Hi,

We recently received an online request from your AWS account to make the following change:

Update the name servers associated with the domain example.com`

Comment: no I haven't received any email, I changed the TTL(seconds ) to 300 still no change

Comment: So you got the name servers from the hostedzone and update it in the name servers section of the DNS right. Where are you managing your dns

Comment: both NS r ze same u can check the pic

Comment: have you registered the dns with Route53

Comment: yes I registered with Route53 the thing is I can access through IP when I try to access using domain it doesn't work

Comment: i think what may have happened is, when you register a domain in Route53 and you goto the registered domains sections to open up your domain, you might see some existing name server entries. In my case, i have copied that values to the hosted zones by mistake. it should be other way around. you get the NS records from the hostedzones and update it in the dns management for the NS record. can you do this again. delete the hosted zone and create it again. get the NS records from the hostedzone to the NS record of the DNS management .

Comment: Ya it worked finally than you!

Comment: What was the issue

Comment: I copied NS from hosted zones to DNS management as u said thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Do you change the Security Group to open port 80 or 443??
I think most of the error can not access is from the firewall, so please check SG, NACL or anything about network
Hope it work